# Angular : When to use "[]" in modules and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting in Angular and i don't understand when to use or not `[]` when declaring (if it's called like this) modules and controllers.

So far, i understood that :

`angular.module('app.prof', []).config(config);` means i *declare* the module `prof`

while `angular.module('app.prof').config(config);` means i *call* it.

But i always end up having the `[]` in the controller and not in the module, and when i have two controllers i don't know what to do anymore.

I just want to understand Angular :(

Edit : adding more details

In my Angular project, i use the Fuse theme with a thing called Yeoman (if i understood well) so i never write `<script>` tags anywhere myself.

for example, i have this module :

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof')
    .config(config);
```

and this controller :

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof', [])
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);
```

My modules and controllers are always declared this way, but sometimes i get errors like "module is not declared" or "controller is not declared"; making me end up randomly putting brackets in the modules or controllers until it works.

EDIT 2 :

here is my main module :

```
angular
    .module('fuse', ['app.prof']);
```

my prof module :

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof')
    .config(config);
```

and my prof controller :

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof', [])
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);
```

this way, the whole thing works fine. But when i do :

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof', [])
    .config(config);
```

and

```
    angular
    .module('app.prof')
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);
```

i get :

[image: errors]

Comment: Oops little typo

Comment: It would help if you gave a specific error corresponding to your example. So instead of saying, "sometimes I get errors like this or that", say "with this example code I see this specific error". You'll be more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: I added a screenshot and more info like you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument are the dependencies for the module. Since you don't have any dependencies at the moment you have an empty array `[]`.

You add the brackets (dependencies) only when you create a new module. Every time when you simply want to use the same module you shouldn't have brackets. So in the end every module should be declared only once with the []. And every other time should be called without.

Also make sure that files and code is imported in the correct order. Otherwise the module is not yet defined when you try to add controllers to it.

Small example. App module with multiple controllers.

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('aCtrl', [ function () {} ]);
angular.module('app').controller('bCtrl', [ function () {} ]);

// ...
```

Long story short. If you declare a module, you need the brackets. If you want to use the module you don't add them.

---

**Edit:** For your edit, once again, you need to make sure that you define and use everything in correct order.

Following depends on `app.prof` which means that `app.prof` declaration needs to be before this row:

```
angular.module('fuse', ['app.prof']);
```

This already suggests that module `app.prof` is declared and you try to add config to it. When app.prof is not declared before you get a similar error as you displayed:

```
angular.module('app.prof')
    .config(config);
```

This declares the module `app.prof` and adds a controller to that module:

```
angular.module('app.prof', [])
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);
```

This declares the `app.prof` module ands immediately adds some config to it:

```
angular.module('app.prof', [])
    .config(config);
```

This adds a controller to an existing module called `app.prof`:

```
angular.module('app.prof')
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);
```

I think you get the idea...

As for a solution you need to declare these in an order similar to this... Doesn't matter if everything is in one file or you load them in file by file but the module declaration order is important.

```
angular.module('app.prof', [])
    .config(config);

angular.module('app.prof')
    .controller('ProfController', ProfController);

angular.module('fuse', ['app.prof']);
```

Controller declaration can probably happen later but anyway you need to pay attention to the ordering. As you said that `fuse` is the main module you need to declare the `app.prof` before.

Comment: To make it clearer : i use the Fuse theme, with a thing called Yeoman if i understood well, so i never import anything myself

Comment: Yeoman might help you to inject the external scripts to the application. But anyway if you want to use the external services inside your own controllers and services, you have to make sure that your Angular application knows about these other modules. Then you need to add those modules as dependencies to your own module like this: `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])`.

Comment: @Orsu I edited the answer in reply to your added questions.

Comment: Thank you for this *very* complete answer ! It's clearer now i think

Answer (score 1):

In angular the "[]" is meant for injecting the external(angular) dependencies to you module and get access of it. refer the below example

```
angular.module('app.proof',['myservice']).controller(function(bootstrap,myservice){
 myservice.callmethod();});
```

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 1):

So when you create a module, you can add other modules as dependencies to it that you're planning to use:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['Restangular', 'UserService', 'otherModule']);
```

Then, when you create a controller, you can make services, factories, etc. available to the controller.

```
app.controller('MyNewController', ['$scope', '$http', 'restangular', function($scope, $http, restangular) {
    // Your code here
    $scope.name = "Daniel";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a Module like this:

```
 angular.module('myModule', []);
```

Similarly,  you can declare a Controller like this:

```
 angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyController', []);
```

When you declare the controller, you're not using the empty array notation in the module, because you're defining a controller on an already existing module.

The empty array (`[]`) that you pass into the module or controller is a placeholder for dependencies you want to inject into your module or controller. See: [AngularJS Depedency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Every AngularJS project has a 'top-level' or root module. This is the module that bootstraps your application together when you use it in accordance with an `ng-app` directive.

In your top-level module(s), you declare your dependencies to the other modules in your application. For example:

```
angular.module('root', ['childModule1', 'childModule2', 'childModule3']);
```

In your controllers, you use dependency injection to inject services, functions, or AngularJS' built-in libraries (such as $http, $sce, or $q) For example:

```
angular.module('root')
    .controller('RootController', ['$window', '$location', 'myRootService']);
```